# WebdriverIO: How to read baseURL value from wdio.conf.js. inside step definition file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, wdio-v4, wdio-v5

I am using WebdriverIO for test automation. In `wdio.conf.js` file I have configured the 'baseUrl' property.

I want to read the 'baseUrl' property value inside my test `.js` file. How can I do this?

Comment: You want to use the one from `wdio.config.js` file, or from `test.js`? You wrote it so sloppy I cannot tell what you want. Please edit your question and be more specific.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**❒ wdio-v5**

Lately, after writing a lot of tests for a project rewrite I've came to believe the best way to store/access global config variables is via the `global` object.

You can define them inside the `wdio.conf.js` file's hooks. I defined mine in the `before` hook:

```js
before: function (capabilities, specs) {
  // =================
  // Assertion Library
  // =================
  const chai    = require('chai');
  global.expect = chai.expect;
  global.assert = chai.assert;
  global.should = chai.should();
  // ======================
  // Miscellaneous Packages
  // ======================
  global.langCode = langCode;
  global.countryCode = countryCode;
  global.request = require('superagent');
  global.allowedStatusCodes = [200, 301],
  // ===============
  // Custom Commands
  // ===============
  require('./test/custom_commands/aFancyMethod');
  require('./test/custom_commands/anotherOne');
  require('./test/custom_commands/andAnotherOne');
},
```

Then, you can access them directly, ***anywhere in your test-files, or page-objects***. This way, you greatly reduce the test-file's footprint (*errr... codeprint*) because you can call these directly in your test case:

```js
describe(`Testing a random URL`, () => {
  it('Should return a HTTP valid status code', async () => {
    // Issue a HTTP request for the given URL:
    await request
      .head('https://random.org')
      .then(res => {
        console.info(`\n> Status code found: ${res.status} | MIME type found: '${res.type}'\n`);
        foundStatusCode = res.status;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.info(`\n> Status code found: ${err.status} | Error response found: '${JSON.stringify(err.response)}'\n`);
        foundStatusCode = err.status;
      });
    // Assert the HTTP Status Code:
    assert.include(allowedStatusCodes, foundStatusCode, `!AssertError: Route yields a bad status code! Got: ${foundStatusCode} | Expected: ${allowedStatusCodes}`);
  });
```

As opposed to always doing `await browser.options.request.head(...`, `browser.options.baseUrl`, etc.

---

**❒ wdio-v4**

All the `wdio.conf.js` file attributes (basically the `config` object name-value pairs) are also stored inside the `browser.options` object.

Thus, a more elegant approach to access your global config values from inside your tests would be as presented below:

```js
> browser.options
{ port: 4444,
  protocol: 'http',
  waitforTimeout: 10000,
  waitforInterval: 500,
  coloredLogs: true,
  deprecationWarnings: false,
  logLevel: 'verbose',
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
  // ... etc ...
}

> browser.options.baseUrl
'http://localhost'
```

---

I'll go on a limb here and presume you want to read the `baseUrl` value from your `wdio.config.js` file, into your `test.js` file.

**TL;DR:** In your `test.js` file heading, add the following:

`var config = require('<pathToWdioConfJS>/wdio.conf.js').config;`

You can then access any `wdio.config.js` value via the `config.<configOption>`, in your case `config.baseUrl`.

---

Lastly, I would **greatly recommend** you read about **[exports and module exports](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)**.

WebdriverIO is built on NodeJS, so you will shoot yourself in the foot on the long run if you don't know how and when to use `exports`, `module.exports`,  `require`, or the difference between them.

Comment: Thankyou iamdanchiv :)

Comment: Thanks this is the best explanation I've seen on how to access variables from the config files!

Answer (score 7):

Use browser.options.baseUrl .   If you use require, you're hard coding from that one file, which is fine, but you cannot do a wdio --baseUrl=http://myTestSite2.net to override the "global" baseUrl.  Which you might want to do in multiple deployments in the future.

Answer (score 2):

BaseUrl is available in the config object browser.config.baseUrl
See https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/a4a5a46f786f8548361d7f86834b38f89dcb1690/packages/webdriverio/webdriverio-core.d.ts#L131

Answer (score 1):

In **wdio.config.js** file define the url like this

```
var baseUrl = 'YOUR URL'
exports.config = {
        baseUrl: baseUrl,
}
```

In Test file use `/` instead of adding complete url in `browser.url('/')`, it will use the baseUrl from the **wdio.config.js** file.

```
browser.url('/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser.options.baseUrl

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just save all your variable in before: function and can be used anywhere in your test. 
like the following example i use retry count wdio config file

```
before: function (capabilities, specs) {
         expect = require('chai').expect;
         should = require('chai').should();
         assert = require('assert');
         retryCount=2;
         browser.maximizeWindow();
```