# Is it possible to access a variable declared in wdio.conf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

In the wdio.conf `onPrepare` I am storing all my feature file's in a array.

```
let listOfFiles = fs.readdirSync(process.cwd() + '/features');
var featureFiles = [];

listOfFiles.map((file) => {
    featureFiles.push(file)
});
```

Is it possible to use the `featureFiles` array in another file?

---

I want to generate an list of feature files during execution and assign it to the variable "featureFiles" (which is declared but has no value to begin with). 
From what I've seen so far it's not possible to do this in wdio.conf as you will always get the value declared for your variable at the beginning.. which in my case is an empty array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebdriverIO: How to read baseURL value from wdio.conf.js. inside step definition file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571364/webdriverio-how-to-read-baseurl-value-from-wdio-conf-js-inside-step-definition)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the file you posted here, add:

```
module.exports = featureFiles
```

In the other file where you'd like to use `featureFiles` you can do something like:

```
const featureFiles = require('path/to/your/first/file`);
```

Comment: When I put a  `module.exports = featureFiles` in the wdio.conf I get the following error on run:

```2019-10-21T08:05:55.056Z INFO @wdio/cli:Launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2019-10-21T08:05:55.057Z ERROR @wdio/cli:Launcher: Missing capabilities, exiting with failure
2019-10-21T08:05:55.058Z INFO @wdio/cli:Launcher: Run onComplete hook```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to use `featureFiles` throughout your test script, then one of the options that we follow is using global object.

In your wdio.conf file, try the following:

```
let featureFiles = [];
...
export.config = {
    ... //some line of code

    //OnPrepare hook
    onPrepare(){
        let listOfFiles = fs.readdirSync(process.cwd() + '/features');

        listOfFiles.map((file) => {
            featureFiles.push(file);
        });
    }

    //before session hook
    beforeSession(){
        global.featureFiles = featureFiles; //assigning the value of featureFiles to a global variable
    }
}
```

Once the above is done. The variable `featureFiles` would be available on all the test files.

NOTE: vscode intellisense might not recognize the variable but you can still use it.

Comment: I've done the above in wdio.conf, then in randomNumber.js I'm trying to console.log(global.featureFiles), however I get an error on featureFiles because "featureFiles does not exist on type 'Global'".

Not sure how I would be able to call featureFiles from test files?

Comment: Hi @Daredevi1 just try `console.log(featureFiles)` ignoring `global`

Comment: Just prints out a blank line

Comment: Ohh .. does featureFile has value before assigning to global? can you try by passing a hard coded value

Comment: If I hardcode a value to featureFile then it prints out the hardcoded value, otherwise it's blank.

Comment: ok .. so the issue is the variable `featureFiles` on the `beforeSession` does not have a value in it. May be you can debug or provide your whole `wdio.conf` file to see where it can be wrong

Comment: You've managed to get it working like this on your wdio.conf?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201269/discussion-between-naveen-thiyagarajan-and-daredevi1).